# Is there a known table or calculation of the ranking system?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

With Counter-Strike: Global Offensive a build-in matchmaking system has been introduced. From now on you can have a rank that displays your skill level.

The more matches you win, the better your ranking will be. If you lose, you will lose some levels of your rank.

But there are exceptions: It is als possible that you are ranked-down if you win a match but your score has been aweful. So how do they calculate the rank?

On the interwebs and ingame you can get several answers:

- If you win three matches in a row, you rank up and vice-versa.
- At the end of the match your score if being compared to the average of your team and the enemies' one.
- Those gold stars you may get at the end of a round do or do not have an impact on that ranking.

I also heard that you can get ranked down after being vote-kicked from a server. So what of these are true; or is it something completely different?

**How does CS:GO calculate your rank after one match?**

And how does a vote-kick influence this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I have found a guide that exactly shows how the *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive* ELO system works.

I have found it in [`German`](https://steamcommunity.com//sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=335372996) and [`English`](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=312582297).

As a very short summary, it states that:

Every rank in CS:GO stands for a specific ELO value. All ELOs from a team are summed up. At the end of the game, those points are spilled across the winning team. Lower ranks get a little bit more points as the high ranks, if they share a team. If you reach the range of another rank, you're going to be upranked. Headshots, positioning and so on are not counted towards those points and don't affect your rank. Well, those MVP stars will give a big ELO bonus on top.

Answer (score 4):

It's a custom Valve's variation of the [Elo Ranking System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) and no official documentation has been released.

Comment: Mh ok. So there has never been a statement about how much impact kills/teamkills/bombing has an impact on this?

Answer (score 0):

also winning 3 games in a row wont for sure rank you up, seeing it as i have won 4 games with an average score on 31.something.13 and not ranked up yet (im silver elite master atm) and that is a quite good score in my rating.

the system is based on you winning a game, and the stars is supposed to give a small burst/amount of elo, but its mostly winning/loosing games.

Comment: Yes, you are right with that. I posted another answer with a complete guide how ELO ranking in CS:GO works.