# Is it possible to reset your competitive rank in Counter-Strike: GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

How do you de-rank in CS:GO competitive? What statistics decide if you derank or not? I'm trying to de-rank to silver one to see what it is like.

Comment: Pretty much lose games? But then again - Losing games purposely is against the rules.

Comment: If you do so than search a team of 5 players and do not play with random players. Really annoing if a lme is last in the team and I have a lost game because he want to be silver. Its bad enough if I lost the game if you on the way back up. I actully do not want to write a tutorial how you downrank in csgo. **This is griefing and for sure not allowed.**

Comment: FYI, CS:GO uses an ELO system. Unfortunatelly not much is known how it calculates your rank exactly, but I think it compares your stat (points) to the average of your team and camparing again to the average of the enemies' team. You may alter your rank IN TERMS OF RULES if you always pass the bomb to your mates, for example. There you "lose" 2 points but you can keep on playing well. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/is-there-a-known-table-or-calculation-of-the-ranking-system

Comment: Don't we all start out as silver? Why would you wanna go back?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to derank would be to lose but losing on purpose is against the rules of playing competative. If I were you I would create a new account and maybe let someone who has never played play your placement games for you and then you take over after they have been placed in silver. Its also worth noting that no one likes to play against smurfs. Its not fun playing a game and loosing because someone on the other team is smurfing and carying their team with 40+ kills.

Comment: Welcome to the edge of silver and gold. :)

Comment: Lol, I like that this is the accepted answer. @xXEaterofSoulsXx is now a multi-account trolling smurf like so many others. Keep cheating yourself and you'll never get good at the game.

Answer (score 11):

**Imagine you're a new player:**

You just bought the game, played a couple rounds and received a Silver 1 rank. Now, your ability to improve your skill is severely dampened because higher skilled players want less of a challenge (or in your case "to see what it's like"). A low level player is going to be very frustrated by this.

It's very possible you will just quit the game because your opponents are too hard.

**Back to logical thinking:**

As you play the game, your rank will change over time. It's Valve's best attempt at putting a number on your skill level. This rank is specifically put in place so that matchmaking can setup a *fair** match for the players.

**A serious problem though:**

High skilled players will buy a second or third copy of the game just so they can play amongst the noobs again. This is called [Smurfing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5670/what-is-smurfing-in-online-games).

These people achieve a high rank but then they get lazy/bored with high-level play. They want a break from tougher opponents and wish to dominate noobs for a while.

This is the equivalent of a playground bully, imo. Smurfing is for low-lifes who haven't realized how sad their life is, yet.

**The answer:**

Valve would never voluntarily allow bullying. The *option* to derank does not exist. You will derank if your performance is poor. You will rank up if your performance is good.